# MS EXCELL =SUM IF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2011

I need to formula for the following

iF a1= 1 then d1 must = b1+c1

tried =sumif(a1,"1",b1:c1)

I only want cell d1 to calculate if cell a1 is '1'

Answer (score 1):

In cell D1, enter:

```
=if(a1=1,b1+c1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your D1 cell , type : =IF(A1=1,B1+C1,"")

In case A1 is not equal to 1 , the result will be empty , if you want to fill it by another value , just put it between the " " , 
Ex : =IF(A1=1,B1+C1,"false")